# JFormattedTextField apagando dados inseridos

Tags: java, swing

Eu tenho 4 TextFields para colocar DDD, numeros antes do hifen, numeros após o hifen e cep.

```
private JTextField ddd=null;

private JTextField antesh=null;

private JTextField depoish=null;
```

E um metodo `formatarTextboxes();`

```
try{
            this.ddd = new JFormattedTextField(new MaskFormatter("###"));
            this.antesh = new JFormattedTextField(new MaskFormatter("#####"));
            this.depoish = new JFormattedTextField(new MaskFormatter("####"));
            this.cep = new JFormattedTextField(new MaskFormatter("#####-###"));
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Porém, quando eu insiro por exemplo, 27 no DDD e aperto tab ou troco de campo para adicionar dados nas outras TextBoxes, o conteudo que eu inseri no DDD simplesmente some, não consigo ver erro no meu código, visto que ele tava funcionando corretamente a uns 2 dias atras sendo que eu nem mexi no código.

Comment: Por favor, adicione um **[mcve]** do seu código para que seja possivel testar e ver o problema em execução.

Comment: Do jeito que está, uma vez que você atribui `null` às variáveis, a primeira tentativa de montar isso em um código que eu possa compilar e testar vai dar `NullPointerException`. É bem provável que o seu problema esteja em uma parte do código que não é a que você postou. Siga a sugestão do colega @Articuno e poste um [mcve].